# storefront product page get a product summary plus right float it to match image alignment

Tags: php, css, woocommerce, storefront

NOTE: NSFW site, maybe some hot images from eBooks covers, no nude but adult romance covers.
I have this page that "brings" a product category, reated with this shortcode

```
[products limit="6" columns="1" category="mf" class="product-shortcode" cat_operator="AND" ]
```

And left-aligned (float) with this CSS

```
/*Align images to the left*/
div.columns-1 {
    float: left
}
```

Ok, I tried this code to get a summary/brief

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'jdn_add_short_description', 9 );
function jdn_add_short_description() {
 // Description linked to product
 $url = get_the_permalink();
 if( $url ) {
 echo '<span class="title-description"><a href="' . $url . '">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</a></span><br />';
 } else {
 echo '<span class="title-description">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</span><br />'; 
 }
}
```

**BUT it gets the summary in ALL pages, not just this one**

What I need:

To get a the product summary/brief JUST in this page, right aligned matching the left aligned images, AND get the Headline, Star Rating, Prie and Get it now also right aligned and Up to math the image, so it all keeps aligned.

is this possible via Code, php, Css, shortcode or is a misconfiguration of woocommerce product?

Comment: Is this just any arbitrary page, or is it “identifiable” as one of the WP default pages in some way? (Single product page, category overview page, something like that.) The you could try and add a condition to your function here, so that it only manipulates the output when it is called “on” that specific page. If it is not identifiable by type or anything generic like that, then hard-coding a check for the post id might be a last resort.

Comment: Thanks, @misorude. I´ll put the question this way; I need to have in some pages (new pages, NO woocommerce default ones) the excerpt of the products displayed. So I have one page with category MMFM called via shortcode, BUT it don´t shows excerpt, so I want to ADD to that shortcode call the excerpt for THAT category in THAT page. How can I do that? maybe a PHP snippet, but I am burnt..can´t get the right one . thanks in advance for some tip. Maybe I am overthinking it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! I wrote my own shortcode as follows, and modified the function, which includes an array of desired pages to show the excerpt, now I only have to style the page so it shows only the image to the left and float the text to the right, no problem.

· Create the function
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'car_excerpt_call', 35, 2);

function car_excerpt_call() {
     if ( is_page( array( "mf-romance", "mfm-romance", "mmf-romance", "mfmm-romance-2" ) ) ) {
     echo '';
     the_excerpt();
     echo '';
     }
}

· Upload it theme or plugin dir with a PHP extension
o /home/wigigx/sitetest.wigigx.com/wp-content/plugins/add_excerpt_shortcode'
· actively register the shortcode within WordPress.
o include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/home/wigigx/sitetest.wigigx.com/wp-content/plugins/add_excerpt_shortcode' );
· The last step is to register the new shortcode with the Shortcode API with the add_shortcode function.
o add_shortcode( 'excerpt_call', 'car_excerpt_call' );

and it works as a charm!!